# You Tube video upload "401 Unauthorized" using youtube-data-api

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload video to Youtube using the java youtube api and getting "401 Unauthorized".

I have created a service account using the developers console and using that .p12 file

Here is the code I am using.

```
public class YouTubeUtils {

private static YouTube youtube;
private static final String VIDEO_FORMAT = "video/*";
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "TestApp";

private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            if (SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL.startsWith("Enter ")) {
                System.err.println(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            String p12Content = Files.readFirstLine(new File("C:/Workspace/TestApp.p12"),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());
            if (p12Content.startsWith("Please")) {
                System.err.println(p12Content);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("C:/Workspace/TestApp.p12"))
            .build();


            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

            VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
            status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

            VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
            snippet.setDescription("Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library "
                    + "on " + cal.getTime());

            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            tags.add("test");
            tags.add("video");
            snippet.setTags(tags);

            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Workspace/small.mp4"));

            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FORMAT,fin);

            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert(
                    "snippet,statistics,status",
                    videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

            MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader)
                        throws IOException {
                    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                    case INITIATION_STARTED:
                        System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                        break;
                    case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                        System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                        System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                        System.out.println("Upload percentage: "
                                + uploader.getProgress());
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                        break;
                    case NOT_STARTED:
                        System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

            // Call the API and upload the video.
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

            // Print data about the newly inserted video from the API
            // response.
            System.out
                    .println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
            System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Title: "
                    + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println("  - Tags: "
                    + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTags());
            System.out.println("  - Privacy Status: "
                    + returnedVideo.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
            System.out.println("  - Video Count: "
                    + returnedVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It prints

Initiation Started

Initiation Completed

and after that I am getting "401 Unauthorized"

Can someone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service_accounts) link, it says **`Service Accounts do not work with the YouTube API`**

Also, please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) link to know how to get authorization credentials and what type of credentials the Youtube API supports.

And [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video) is an example of uploading a video to youtube using OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. Should I be using the "Installed Application" for this purpose?

Comment: credentials can be obtained from Google developer console, please refer the above links for obtaining credentials and an example is also referred above.

Comment: I got it working. But the problem is, it opens up the browser to authorize the user. Is there a way to bypass this and automatically authorize the user

Comment: I think you need to have client_secrets.json downloaded from the Google developer console credentials and have Auth class , refer to https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java in your imports, refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video .

Comment: Would you mind to vote-up if my answer helped you in someway.Thanks :)